# Add preview image wrappers before upload in dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, dropzone.js

Is it possible to set the image preview wrappers before the upload as exmaple( https://snag.gy/cgvsUL.jpg), and after choosing the files fill the wrappers with the dropzone preview template?

There is event on "addedfile" but it fires after the file added. Is there something like "beforeaddefile" to queue, so I could catch where to put the uploaded files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `addedfile` is fired just before the file is added into the preview container.
You can implement this event to do what you are trying to achieve.

```
this.on("addedfile", function (file) {
    file.previewElement.....("do your stuff");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, found everything in documentation, there are plenty useful events to play with.